# InstStub.exe - What is it and do I need it?

Tags: windows, norton-360

I am running Windows 8.1 and have been using Norton 360 for few years. A [new icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prHBz.jpg) popped up in the notification area of my taskbar today, saying "Restart your computer to complete installation." Everything about it seemed suspicious at first (the right click menu looks different from all others), so I tried (and failed) to end the task and found out it was part of Norton 360. The Details tab of the Task Manager showed it was called InstStub.exe.

What is InstStub.exe for, and should I remove it? And why might it appear so suddenly? Thank you for your help.

Update: To clarify, are the "complete installation" popups normal or a sign that this may be malware disguised as Norton software?

Comment: A simple search for InstStub.exe will give you a number of references to a lot of information.

Comment: I had already done the search and the unanswered question it left me with is, are the "complete installation" popups normal or a sign that this may be malware disguised as Norton software?

Comment: I don't see that question above.

Comment: I do now. :) ...

Comment: http://community.norton.com/en/forums/new-icon-restart-your-computer-complete-installation